# Why are singular values of "complex" matrices always real and non-negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, svd

I've already read the following related questions on math.SE:

- [Why can't singular values be complex numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2213751)
- [Clarification on the SVD of a complex matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628541)
- [Why are singular values always non-negative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2060572)
- [Convention on non-negative singular values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170746)

The conclusion they seem to agree on is the following:

For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} $, its singular values are **real non-negative**.

I do not see, however, how can this be the case for $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, even though in most answers, people say it is the same as for real matrices.

### Usual argument for singular values of $A  \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} $ being real non-negative:

The SVD of $A$ is:
$$
A = U S V^T
$$
We have
$$
B = A^T A = V S^T U^T U S V^T = V S^T S V^T
$$
where $S^T S$ is diagonal with elements $\sigma_i^2$, where $\sigma_i$ are the singular values of $A$.
Now, $\sigma_i^2$ are **real-nonegative** because they can be seen as the eigenvalues $\lambda_i=\sigma_i^2$ of the symmetric, positive-definite, matrix $B = V \Lambda V^T$ (i.e., $\Lambda = S^T S$).

Using $\lambda_i=\sigma_i^2 \ge 0$ to solve for $\sigma_i$, we find that:

- $\sigma_i$ is **real** because if it were complex, then the only way $\sigma_i^2$ would be real is if $\sigma_i$ is real or pure imaginary. However, in the latter case we get $\sigma_i^2$ negative, which contradicts $\sigma_i^2 \ge 0$.
- $\sigma_i$ is the square-root of $\lambda_i$, which can be positive or negative. By convention, however, we take the **positive** square-root.

Hence, 
$$
\sigma_i \text{ are real-nonnegative themselves.}
$$

### A try for a similar argument for singular values of $A  \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n} $ :

The SVD of $A$ is:
$$
A = U S V^H
$$
We have
$$
B = A^H A = V S^H U^H U S V^H = V S^H S V^H
$$
where $S^H S$ is diagonal with elements $|\sigma_i|^2$, where $\sigma_i$ are the singular values of $A$.
Now, $|\sigma_i|^2$ are **real-nonnegative** because of the modulus square, and they can also be seen as the eigenvalues $\lambda_i=|\sigma_i|^2$ of the Hermitian, positive-definite, matrix $B = V \Lambda V^H$ (i.e., $\Lambda = S^H S$).

Using $\lambda_i=|\sigma_i|^2 \ge 0$, how can one solve for $\sigma_i$ and prove it is **real-nonnegative**?

Particularly, what prevents $\sigma_i$ from being complex?

Comment: Because a complex number times its conjugate is always real and positive.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The  result is that a complex matrix $A$ *has* a factorization of form $A=USV^H$ where $S$ is nonnegative real diagonal and $U$ and $V$ are "unitary" in the sense that they might be rectangular but $U^HU$ and $V^HV$ are identity matrices. To produce it one takes the positive square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^H$ and $A^HA$.

No one asserts that *all* factorizations of $A$ as a product of form $USV^H$ with "unitary" $U$ and $V$ and diagonal $S$ must have all entries of $S$ nonnegative real.

Take, for instance, factorizations of form $A=UDD^{-1}SV^H$ where $D$ is diagonal with complex numbers of unit magnitude on the diagonal.  If $U$ is "unitary" so is $UD$, if $S$ is diagonal, so is $D^{-1}S$.  So if there is a standard SVD decomposition $A=USV^H$ there are non-standard ones too, that have non-positive diagonal middle factors.

More concretely: suppose $A=USV^H$ is an SVD in the standard sense.  Then $A=(-U)(-S)V^H$ is also true, and $-U$ is  "unitary" since  $U$ is.  But $-S$ is not positive on its diagonal.  The factorization $A=(-U)(-S)V^H$ holds, but is not a standard SVD factorization.

So the answer boils down to this: the middle factor in an SVD is *defined* to be nonnegative real diagonal.

Comment: So, nothing prevents $\sigma_i$ from being complex. It's just that we've chosen among the possible choices for $\sigma_i$ one particular choice and called the relative factorization SVD.

Comment: Exactly.  The wide range of applications of the SVD constitutes a kind of justification for the definition we've chosen.